# Will there be a 'Home' icon on the launcher of desktop-unity?

Tags: unity, launcher

In order for me to access my 'Home' currently in Unity, I have to click on 'Deleted Items' and then the 'Home' button which is situated in the toolbar on the Nautilus window. It would be quite convenient having a 'Home' icon on Unity's launcher for quick access to the users common folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in the [the blueprint](https://blueprints.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-bringing-desktop-and-netbook-image-closer) the default items in the launcher for 11.04 will be:

- nautilus on both cases
- firefox
- tomboy
- ubuntu one

The "nautilus" will be a shortcut to your home folder. The "both cases" means it will be there whether you're on a netbook or a normal desktop.